# Can we hide fields on a person's profile page?

Tags: chatter, profile, user-admin

Specifically, I'd like to hide the Manager field. Is this possible?
It doesn't seem to be so.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manager info is only displayed when the manager relationship is entered in the user's details (settings page). Once the information is in there, there will be no way to prevent the information to show on the profile page, except building a Visualforce page to replace the default profile page.

Comment: thank you. This is a disappointing limitation to not be able to hide the manager.